# Laravel Sanctum - getting 401 on auth:sanctum with token returned after login

Tags: laravel, laravel-sanctum

I have the following login method:

```
public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'email'       => 'required|email',
            'password'    => 'required',
            'device_name' => 'required'
        ]);

        $user = User::where('email', $request->email)->first();

        if (! $user || ! Hash::check($request->password, $user->password)) {
            throw ValidationException::withMessages([
                'email' => ['The provided credentials are incorrect.'],
            ]);
        }

        return response([
            'user'          => $user,
            'session_token' => $user->createToken($request->device_name)->plainTextToken,
        ], 201);
    }
```

This method is working and returning token is a format similar to this:

```
5|5lR3o7vEzlm6iOieKxTW2pco1msKLN0WHb0Ozxv2relwIB4eJetyPnADOu6Dp0griYY7U1YZJEAqk6Ct
```

When I try to use a route behind **auth:sanctum** with that token I am getting

```
401 - "message": "Unauthenticated."
```

I am using the latest Laravel 7. Configuration:

**.env**

```
APP_URL=http://localhost:9099
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=http://localhost:9099
```

**cors.php**

```
'paths' => ['api/v1/*'],
```

I am using Insomnia for API testing. The login method works and also any route that doesn't use **auth:sanctum** middleware.
Any idea what am I doing wrong here?

[image: Insomnia setup]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are running the server on port 9099 try setting your .env file to:

```
SESSION_DOMAIN=http://localhost
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=http://localhost:9099
```

SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS should be set the same as the url in your browser

Comment: `SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS` should not have protocol prefix and it can have multiple domains in it. To use it properly set something like `SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=localhost:9099,localhost:8080`

Answer (score 0):

I had my expiration set as `null` and I kept getting `401 errors`. When I changed it to `60*24*30` it works.